# Webview post request vs http post request in android

Tags: android, webview, httprequest

I am working on payment integration with bank. When I do http post request with url and formencoded data , I am getting error html page. But if I am doing the same using webview , I am getting successul otp page of the bank. I am not sure why this response is different. As of now we have to do only http request and wanted the same response as returned by webview. I have tested same request in postman. I am getting successful otp page. What can be possible reason?

Comment: Can you add your code, please

Comment: You want http request code or webview request code?

Comment: The one that fails, I guess. Also copy the curl command from Postman

Comment: that's quiet sensitive data to share. What else information I can provide you?

Comment: that's quiet sensitive data to share. What else information I can provide you?

Comment: I think that WebView sends some extra fields or headers

Comment: Remove the authentication data and url, then. It's hard to help you without a [mcve] because how are we supposed to know what format your server needs the data?

Comment: @MangeshKadam did you find a solution to this?
I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: no. No luck so far. Gave up on the issue.